# When you wait in line at grocery store: Por favor vaya al registro numero 1

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, verbos, pronombres

Is the sentence *Please go to register number 1* correctly translated in Spanish as *Por favor vaya al registro numero 1*?

Can the verb be used as noun in this case?

Comment: Which verb? "Register" is not a verb in "register number 1".

Comment: Many sign makers use the infinitive rather than the imperative.  This gets around  whether to use *vaya* or *ve*.

Answer (score 6):

In Argentina (and supposedly in other Spanish-speaking countries too), one would hear:

- Por favor vaya / diríjase a la caja número uno. ("caja" meaning "cashier")

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by *register*, your translation is almost correct. You are just missing a comma after *por favor*:

> Por favor, vaya al registro número 1

In Spanish, this additions with a meaning outside the main sentence are always enclosed in commas. In this case, *por favor* adds nothing to the meaning of the main sentence (*vaya al registro número 1*), so you separate it using a comma.

I don't understand what you mean with using the verb as a noun; the only verb is *go* and I cannot see which noun you intend to use instead.